# CSS selector for multiple different class name combinations

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want to hide a few classes and the classes look like 
`.class-1, .class-2, .class-3..... .class-60` and so on.

I want to hide all class20s, class30s classes and typing each class line is not efficient way to do

```
.class21,
.class22,
.class23 {
  display: none;
}
```

I'd like to know is it possible to select classes like below, but if I use something like below, `class2` and `class3` is selected.

```
[class^="class2*"],
[class^="class3*"] {
 display: none;
}
```

or scss way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always negate `.class2` and `.class3` using the [`:not()` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not):

```
[class^="class2"]:not(.class2),
[class^="class3"]:not(.class3) {
  color: #f00;
}
```

```css
[class^="class2"]:not(.class2),
[class^="class3"]:not(.class3) {
  color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<div class="class1">don't select</div>
<div class="class2">don't select</div>
<div class="class3">don't select</div>
<div class="class4">don't select</div>

<div class="class21">select</div>
<div class="class22">select</div>
<div class="class23">select</div>
<div class="class24">select</div>

<div class="class31">select</div>
<div class="class32">select</div>
<div class="class33">select</div>
<div class="class34">select</div>
```

Keep in mind that the attribute selector `[class^="class2"]` will select class attributes *starting* with the substring `class2`. If you want to cover cases where there are multiple classes and `class2` isn't the first class, then it gets a little complex because you also need to account for whitespace:

```
[class^="class2"]:not(.class2),
[class*=" class2"]:not(.class2),
[class^="class3"]:not(.class3),
[class*=" class3"]:not(.class3) {
  color: #f00;
}
```

```css
[class^="class2"]:not(.class2),
[class*=" class2"]:not(.class2),
[class^="class3"]:not(.class3),
[class*=" class3"]:not(.class3) {
  color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<div class="another class1">don't select</div>
<div class="another class2">don't select</div>
<div class="another class3">don't select</div>
<div class="another class4">don't select</div>

<div class="another class21">select</div>
<div class="another class22">select</div>
<div class="another class23">select</div>
<div class="another class24">select</div>

<div class="another class31">select</div>
<div class="another class32">select</div>
<div class="another class33">select</div>
<div class="another class34">select</div>
```

You could alternatively just select all `.class2*`/`.class3*` combinations, and then override the CSS for `.class2`/`.class3` back to their initial state.

For instance:

```
[class^="class2"],
[class^="class3"] {
  color: #f00;
}

.class2,
.class3 {
  /* Reset all styles back to their initial state */
  color: initial;
}
```

```css
[class^="class2"],
[class^="class3"] {
  color: #f00;
}

.class2,
.class3 {
  /* Reset all styles back to their initial state */
  color: initial;
}
```

```html
<div class="class1">don't select</div>
<div class="class2">don't select</div>
<div class="class3">don't select</div>
<div class="class4">don't select</div>

<div class="class21">select</div>
<div class="class22">select</div>
<div class="class23">select</div>
<div class="class24">select</div>

<div class="class31">select</div>
<div class="class32">select</div>
<div class="class33">select</div>
<div class="class34">select</div>
```

Due to how inflexible these approaches are, elements with a class such as `class2-block` will also be selected since the end of the class isn't being checked.

With that being said, it may be safer just to use a CSS preprocessor to generate the combinations.

For instance, here is a simple loop in LESS:

```
.class39 {
  color: #f00;
}

@iterations: 38;
.loop (@i) when (@i > 19) {
  .class@{i}:extend(.class39) {}
  .loop(@i - 1);
}
.loop (@iterations);
```

Which would compile to:

```
.class39, .class38, .class37, .class36, .class35, .class34, .class33,
.class32, .class31, .class30, .class29, .class28, .class27, .class26,
.class25, .class24, .class23, .class22, .class21, .class20 {
  color: #f00;
}
```

```css
.class39, .class38, .class37, .class36, .class35, .class34, .class33,
.class32, .class31, .class30, .class29, .class28, .class27, .class26,
.class25, .class24, .class23, .class22, .class21, .class20 {
  color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<div class="class1">don't select</div>
<div class="class2">don't select</div>
<div class="class3">don't select</div>
<div class="class4">don't select</div>

<div class="class21">select</div>
<div class="class22">select</div>
<div class="class23">select</div>
<div class="class24">select</div>

<div class="class31">select</div>
<div class="class32">select</div>
<div class="class33">select</div>
<div class="class34">select</div>
```

Likewise, you could also use the following SCSS:

```
$count: 20;

%class-list {
  color: #f00;
}

@mixin class-loop {
  @for $i from 39 through $count {
      .class#{$i} { @extend %class-list; }
  }
}

@include class-loop;
```

Which would compile to the same as the LESS results.

Answer (score 2):

Use `*=` more explanation about [the 30 css selectors you must memorize](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048) (starts to get interesting in this case from point 10)

```css
/* get all divs with classes containing *class* */
div[class*=class] {
  border: solid 2px orange;
}

/* get all divs with classes containing *class2* */
div[class*=class2]{
  border: solid 2px green;
}
```

```html
<div class="class21">xxx</div>
<div class="class22">xxx</div>
<div class="class23">xxx</div>
<div class="class24">xxx</div>

<div class="class31">xxx</div>
<div class="class32">xxx</div>
<div class="class33">xxx</div>
<div class="class34">xxx</div>
```

Comment: `*=class2` will hide `class2` `class2X`, `class2XX` etc. even `myclass2`

Comment: @pol exactly, you got it!

Comment: Thanks for the answer `*=class2` will impact class2* but also `class2` itself

Comment: @olo yes and as pol mentioned also `myclass2`, `iconclass2` and even `icon no-class2` and so on

Comment: @olo what I'm trying to show with this answer is a way to select a range of classes which give you the possiblity to select exactly the ones you need. The rest is normal use of CSS and [selectors specificity](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#specificity)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `nth-child` **CSS** property to target a range of elements. First of all, I'd like you to change your class values from `class1`..`class60` to just a **class** as is:

```
<ul>
  <li class="class"></li> <!-- 1st item -->
  ...
  <li class="class"></li> <!-- 60th item -->
</ul>
```

Then you can use the following **CSS** declaration to hide the `li` items from *20th to 39th*.

```
li:nth-child(n+20):nth-child(-n+39) {
  display: none;
}
```